# How do I stop regex after finding "Message: "?

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm splitting the body of a JSON message with the regex ":|\n" and storing the values into an array. I would like to get assistance with stopping my regex expression from splitting the message once it finds "Message: ".

In the JSON body, each section is separated by a new line, so the body looks similar to this:

{"body": "Name: Alfred Alonso\nCompany: null\nEmail: 123@abc.com\nPhone Number: 123-456-9999\nProject Type: Existing\nContact by: Email\nTime Frame: within 1 month\nMessage: Hello,\nThis is my message.\nThank You,\nJohn Doe"}

The code below works perfectly when the user doesn't create a new line within the message, so the entire message gets stored as one array value.

Thank you to anyone that can help me fix this!

```
String[] messArr = body.split(":|\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < messArr.length; i++)
        messArr[i] = messArr[i].trim();

    if ("xxx".equals(eventSourceARN)) {

        name = messArr[1];

        String[] temp;
        String delimiter = " ";

        temp = name.split(delimiter);
        name = temp[0];
        String lastName = temp[1];

        company = messArr[3];
        email = messArr[5];
        phoneNumber = messArr[7];
        projectType = messArr[9];
        contactBy = messArr[11];
        timeFrame = messArr[13];
        message = messArr[15];
```

I would like

```
messArr[14] = "Message"
messArr[15] = "Hello, This is my message. Thank you, John Doe"
```

This is what I get
[..., Message, Hello,, This is my message., Thank You, John Doe].

```
messArr[14] = "Message"
messArr[15] = "Hello,"
messArr[16] = "This is my message."
messArr[17] = "Thank You,"
messArr[18] = "John Doe"
```

Comment: If you have JSON to parse, I'd suggest to use a proper JSON parser.

Comment: use a json parser it is better

Comment: @mrzasa I'm using the ObjectMapper from Jackson.

Comment: or you can first split with text "Message" first and then process the remaining text

Comment: `split` has an optional second (often overseen) argument that limits the number of *found* tokens... (but still not the best *tool* for parsing)

Comment: You could _technically_ do something like `body.substring(body.indexOf("Message:") + "Message:".length() + 1,  body.length() - 2)`.  ... but don't do this.  Really should use a JSON parser.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger This worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: but just hope the order of the values does never change...  (e.g. Company comes first)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `split`, you can use a `find` loop, e.g.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^:\\v]+): |((?<=Message: )(?s:.*)|(?<!$).*)\\R?");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Matcher m = p.matcher(input); m.find(); )
    result.add(m.start(1) != -1 ? m.group(1) : m.group(2));
```

*Test*

```
String input = "Name: Alfred Alonso\n" +
               "Company: null\n" +
               "Email: 123@abc.com\n" +
               "Phone Number: 123-456-9999\n" +
               "Project Type: Existing\n" +
               "Contact by: Email\n" +
               "Time Frame: within 1 month\n" +
               "Message: Hello,\n" +
               "This is my message.\n" +
               "Thank You,\n" +
               "John Doe";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^:\\v]+): |((?<=Message: )(?s:.*)|(?!$).*)\\R?");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Matcher m = p.matcher(input); m.find(); )
    result.add(m.start(1) != -1 ? m.group(1) : m.group(2));
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    System.out.println("result[" + i + "]: " + result.get(i));
```

*Output*

```
result[0]: Name
result[1]: Alfred Alonso
result[2]: Company
result[3]: null
result[4]: Email
result[5]: 123@abc.com
result[6]: Phone Number
result[7]: 123-456-9999
result[8]: Project Type
result[9]: Existing
result[10]: Contact by
result[11]: Email
result[12]: Time Frame
result[13]: within 1 month
result[14]: Message
result[15]: Hello,
This is my message.
Thank You,
John Doe
```

*Explanation*

- Match one of:

  - `(` Start capture #1

    - `[^:\v]+` Match one or more characters that are not a `:` or a linebreak
  - `)` End capture #1
  - `:` Match, but don't capture, a `:` and a space *(which SO is hiding here)*
- `|` or:

  - `(` Start capture #2

    - Match one of:

      - `(?<=Message: )(?s:.*)` Rest of input, i.e. all text including linebreaks, if the text is immediately preceded by "Message: "
    - `|` or:

      - `(?!$)` Don't match if we're already at end-of-input
      - `.*` Match 0 or more characters up to end-of-line, excluding the EOL
  - `)` End capture #2
  - `\\R?` Match, but don't capture, an optional linebreak. This doesn't apply to `Message` text, and is optional in case there is no `Message` text and no linebreak after last value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, you could do exactly what you are doing and then put things together later. As you are trimming, notice where it says Message, then know that the Message is in the next slot and beyond. Then put it back together.

```
int messagePosition = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < messArr.length; i++){
    messArr[i] = messArr[i].trim();
    if (i>0 && messArr[i-1].equals("Message")){
        messagePosition =i;
    }
}
if (messagePosition > -1){
    for (int i=messagePosition+1; i <messArr.length; i++){
        messArr[messagePosition]=messArr[messagePosition]+" "+messArr[i];
    }
}
```

One downside is that because arrays are fixed size, you need to act as if there is nothing beyond the messagePosition. So any calculations with length will be misleading. If for some reason you are worried you will look in the slots beyond, you could add `messArr[i]="";` to the second for loop after the concatenation step.